# Solving differential equation $(2x-y)dx+(4x+y-6)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The task is to solve the differential equation $$(2x-y)dx+(4x+y-6)dy=0$$ To solve this, I let $y$ be the dependent variable so that the equation becomes $2x-y+(4x+y-6)y'=0$ and isolating $y'$ I got $$y'=-\dfrac{2x-y}{4x+y-6}$$ Here, I find difficulty on how to rewrite the equation into a first order separable ODE in the form $$N(y)\cdot y'=M(x)$$ as to what value of $y$ containing $v$ should I substitute in order to rewrite the equation into separable form. I have used a software on how to solve this, it suggests on substituting $$y=\dfrac{2x-4xv+6v}{v+1}$$ However, I find it difficult to trace back how did the software find the value of $y$ that will be used in the substitution.

Comment: The proposed variable change is $v=\frac{2x-y}{4x+y-6}$. But I don't think it gives a separable ODE. In any case it is not the usual method for this type of equation.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute: 
$$x=X+A,\\ y=Y+B$$
Then you get:
$$Y'=-\dfrac {2X-Y+2A-B}{4X+Y+4A+B-6}$$
$$Y'=-\dfrac {2X-Y}{4X+Y}$$
Find $A,B$ such that 
$$2A-B=0, \\ 4A+B-6=0$$
Then the DE becomes homogeneous. Substitute $Y=VX$

---